# Excel - group multiple columns separately

Tags: excel

I have the following data in Excel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XHrI.png)
Is it possible to group the columns Share, Value and Frequency separately? When I try to group them separately, they all end up in the same Group.

Also, I want to hide some columns (marked with red) and when expanding the Group, to remain hided. Now if I hide them and then expand the group, they are showed.

Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVClD.png)

Comment: You have to group them one at a time. So first select all the columns of "Share" then go to Data -> Group. Then select the next columns and repeat. You should have 3 separat groupings

Comment: I tried to do that; but after I select the second group, it combines with the first one and then with the third one the same.

Comment: I see. You need to insert a column between the groups, otherwise Excel will group them together. Just add a new column between Share and Value and then you can group them individually